# Why does this GET request warrant a 400 - Bad Request response?

Tags: c, http, tcp, client

```
sprintf(request, "Get %s HTTP/1.1\r\n Host: %s\r\n\r\n", secondHalf, firstHalf);
```

Say I enter "example.com/example.html", secondHalf would be "example.html" and firstHalf would be "/example.com".

Why is this not a valid GET request?

Comment: Possible problems 1) `Get` should be `GET` 2) there's a space in front of `Host` 3) the `/` in firstHalf

Comment: I somehow managed to not realize Get was not GET despite typing "GET" in this question twice. This and the space seem to be the issue.

Comment: Yes, I'll admit being amused that it was `GET` everywhere except where it mattered :) Glad to hear you got it working. Cheers.